# Change bufferCount value at runtime

Tags: javascript, rxjs6

Using rxjs6

```
  // should be dynamic
  const bufferSize = 3

  interval(100)
    .pipe(bufferCount(bufferSize))
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

I want to change a bufferSize at runtime without recreating a stream. Any ideas how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new operator to configure bufferCount with Observable. Usage example:

```
function testDynamicBuffer() {
  const source = interval(50)

  // initial buffer size is 4
  const bufferSource = new BehaviorSubject<number>(4)

  const bufferedSource = source
    .pipe(dynamicBufferCount(bufferSource))
    .subscribe(x => console.log(x))

  setTimeout(() => bufferSource.next(2), 1000)
  setTimeout(() => bufferSource.next(3), 1500)
  setTimeout(() => bufferSource.next(40), 1873)
  setTimeout(() => bufferSource.next(2), 4593)
  setTimeout(() => bufferSource.next(9), 8764)

  setTimeout(() => bufferedSource.unsubscribe(), 10764)
}

testDynamicBuffer()
```

https://github.com/kigorw/dynamicBufferCount